# Visualforce State and Country Picklists - Standard Fields

Tags: visualforce, account, standard-objects, country-and-state, standard-field

**Question**

Can a `Visualforce Page` be built so it displays the actual picklist values and dependencies for fields which incorporate [`State and Country Picklists`](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/202/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/state_country_picklists_impl_guide.pdf)? I tried using Field Sets as well as hard-coded field references, and either way it just displays a text input.

**MVR Markup**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Account.BillingStreet}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!Account.BillingCity}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!Account.BillingState}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!Account.BillingPostalCode}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!Account.BillingCountry}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Screenshot**

[image: BillingAddress inputFields]

The edit page displays the picklist as expected:

[image: BillingAddress detail]

Comment: Bold formatting seems to have disappeared...

Comment: Try using the corresponding code field e.g. `{!Account.BillingStateCode}` - I think that presents the picklist values.

Comment: @Keith The field labels on the edit page hint as much. Good idea, and it worked. Post as an answer and I will accept.

Comment: Done. Couldn't find any mention of that in the docs though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the corresponding code field in the Visualforce e.g. `{!Account.BillingStateCode}` instead of `{!Account.BillingState}`will present the picklist values.